# Sort followed documents ascending/descending not working

Tags: javascript

I have got a script which retrieves the followed documents by the current user and displays them inside a webpart.
It has 2 buttons which sort them ascending or descending and each row has a button to unfollow the document.

Now to the problem:
After I've unfollowed a document I am not able to sort them anymore.

Here is the code for the ascending button:

```
$('#sortDocsAscending').click( function(){
    console.log("click");
    sortDocValue = 1;
    $(".documentClassic").fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            doJSONDoc("/_api/social.following/my/followed%28types=2%29", renderDocSuccess, renderSiteFail);
    });
});
```

the sort algorithm:

```
if(sortDocValue == 1){
    documentResults.sort(function(a, b){
    var nameA=a.Name.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.Name.toLowerCase();
    if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
        return -1 
    if (nameA > nameB)
        return 1
    return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
})
```

here is also the function to remove an item:

```
function removeLi(id){
    $(element).parent().parent().remove();
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Is my problem somewhere in there?

Answer (score 0):

The last function seems to be problematic. The assignment should happen first.

It should be -

```
function removeLi(id)
{
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  $(element).parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Not sure if it would solve the problem.